# Django: derive permissions from user_type

Tags: django

I am implementing permissions functionality into my webapp. The requirements specified by the customer are that users can perform some actions based on what kind of user they are. The kind of user is defined based on a combination of `user_type:user_role`. This is the model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    usertype = models.IntegerField(choices=UserType.CHOICES, default=UserType.BUYER_USER)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=UserRole.CHOICES, default=UserRole.NORMAL_USER)
```

For example we can have:

- `adviser:regular`: can `manager_orders`
- `adviser:admin`: can do what an `adviser:regular` does and also `manage_advisers` (this is no django `admin`, but an admin for advisers!)

(there are more `user_type:user_role`)

This seems to conflict with the [django permission system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization), which is based on **what permission a user has**, instead of **what kind of user it is**.

That is, when using the django permission system I need to define all possible permissions and assign those permissions to the affected user. Instead, with the approach that I am planning, I would need to *derive*  the permission from the `user_type:user_role`.

Does it make sense to use the django permission system in this context? How can I derive the permission from the `user_type:user_role`

Comment: Well, if it's possible, why don't use start using django `groups` concept? You could create one group and assign a certain permission to that group, then all users in the group would inherit that permission. In this case, the question `what kind of user it is` could be answered by checking the group that he/she belongs to.

Comment: @ShangWang: thanks, but still unclear. I would still have (possibly) conflicting information: on the one hand the user_type:user_role, on the other hand the group a user belongs to. Since the group is the deciding parameter, the user_type:user_role is not relevant. This is exactly what I want to avoid: I want to derive the permissions directly from the user_type:user_role, not from any other setting (either permission or group)

Comment: What I suggest doesn't really apply to your model, it's an alternative approach that fits more to django than your original design. I don't really know how could you apply your way with a permission system(but definitely something customized), but you might find it easier to use group to represent `usertype` and `role`.

Comment: @ShangWang: actually, what you say makes a lot of sense. Could you add that as answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to stick to @ShangWangs approach in the comments, I would recommend taking a look at [Django Object Based Permissions](https://code.osuosl.org/projects/object-permissions/wiki/Using).
With this, you are able to grant permissions to users for objects that derive from a super Model you want to apply the permissions to.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Django docs, you can do this with a custom authentication backend:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends

Any time Django needs to check if a user has a particular permission it will delegate to the auth backend, passing the current user object as an arg. At this point you can check the `usertype` and `role` fields and return appropriate boolean value.

example from the docs:

```
class SettingsBackend(object):
    ...
    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        if user_obj.username == settings.ADMIN_LOGIN:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

From what you describe in your question you do not need the complication of 'object-level' permissions as mentioned by others (since you don't have unique permissions for each user, they are based on the type and role)

Comment: Thanks, interesting. But after the comments from @ShangWang I have the impression that defining my "user_types" as groups is quite easy also. I do not even need to define a user_type, since that is implicit in the group.